# How to Serve Static Files (in ~/Content) Via HTTPS in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application to which I've just added an area.  Links inside the area (to images, JavaScript files, CSS etc.) default to https.  However, MVC doesn't seem to serve static content inside the `~/Content` directory over https.

I've pored over internet documentation, and I've found no information about how MVC treats the `~/Content` directory differently, or how to get it to serve static files over https.

I was hoping it would be as easy as a Web.config entry that says "allow static files to be served via https" but I've found no such thing.

The only option I've come up with is to write a custom controller to serve my static content, but this seems so very wrong.  What am I missing?

UPDATE: to answer Joe's question below, the views themselves are being served over https.  For static content, like JavaScript files, I'm using absolute URLs without protocol or domains.  For example:

```
<script "/Areas/Admin/Content/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Because the protocol of the page is https, the browser is making a request for `https://localhost:5300/Areas/Admin/Content/js/jquery.js` (naturally).  Make the protocol http and that file is served correctly: make it https, and I get an error.

UPDATE: I was foolishly not reading the error carefully.  There's more detail in there, but it's still got me baffled.  The error I get when I try to access `https://localhost:5300/Areas/Admin/Content/js/jquery.js` is:

```
Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: 
Failed to start monitoring changes to
'C:\Users\ethan\Documents\gitwork\SampleWebSite\admin\content\web.config'
because access is denied.
```

Why is it looking for a Web.config file in that directory?

Comment: So it's writing out the markup using the full URL including `http://`? Seems a little weird - MVC always gives me relative paths when I put content on the page, so a relative path will use the same protocol as the page. Can you provide an example of your `img` or `script` or whatever tag?

Comment: I've got no idea on at error - that's a strange one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is that you don't use "~"